# SQL: Deleting something that is used less than two times in an other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following tables:

- Employee (#PNo, Name, *ANo, Salary)
- Department (#ANo, AName)
- Hotel (#HNo, HName, HCategory, ZIP, City)
- Journey (#*Employee, #*Hotel, #BeginningDate, Duration, Costs)

(#=primary key, *=foreign key)

I want to delete all hotels which have been booked with a maximum of one stay and tried it with

```
DELETE hotel FROM hotel
INNER JOIN journey ON journey.Hotel = hotel.HNo
WHERE COUNT(journey.Hotel) < 2;
```

But that doesn't work. All I get is the following error:

> "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

How can I connect the two tables and delete the hotels in the table "hotel" that were not booked more than ones?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Please do not use the tags of databases you are not using. Please add the tag of only the database you are using, please.

Comment: I'm using MySQL

And sorry, I'm new to SQL and therefore I'm not good at it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join hotel with journey and count any column from journey table. This will return hotels + journey count, including hotels with zero journeys.

```
DELETE FROM hotel
WHERE HNo IN (SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT hotel.HNo
    FROM hotel
    LEFT JOIN journey ON hotel.HNo = journey.Hotel
    GROUP BY hotel.HNo
    HAVING COUNT(journey.Hotel) < 2
) AS foobar)
```

The sub-sub-query trick is [described here](http://dasunhegoda.com/1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-table_name-for-update-in-from-clause/104/).

Comment: Tried this and now I get the following error:

"#1093 - Table 'hotel' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data"

Comment: MySQL has its own rules. See revised answer.

Answer (score 4):

ANSI SQL complaint answer:

```
DELETE hotel FROM hotel
WHERE HNo not in (select Hotel 
                  from journey
                  group by Hotel
                  having count(*) >= 2)
```

The sub-query will return Hotels that exist more than once in the journey table.

Comment: Maybe comment on why the join would not give the expected results. +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I can't figure out how it would, since I don't understand that DELETE JOIN syntax at all

Comment: It will not delete hotels that are not present in journey at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM hotel 
WHERE HNo IN (SELECT hotel.HNo 
                FROM hotel 
                JOIN journey on (journey.hotel = hotel.HNo) 
                GROUP BY hotel.HNo 
                HAVING count(hotel.HNo) < 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM hotel WHERE secnum IN (SELECT secnum FROM journey GROUP BY secnum HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 )